# Connect and sudden disconnect of ap-hotspot in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, ubuntu-14.04

I am having this problem since I first learned to create the ap-hotspot in Ubuntu 14.04 to share my ethernet over wifi. To create this ap-hotspot I followed these steps:

1. Create a wifi connection from the network connections dialog box.

1. Here I first assign the Connection name.
2. Use the same name as the Connection name for SSID (although it doesn't matter, I think).
3. Then leave the Mode as it is (to be changed later).
4. Select the *Device Mac Address* from the dropdown menu.
5. Select WPA and WPA2 Personal as Security mode and then assign a password.
6. Select *Shared to Other Computers* option in the IPV4 method dropdown menu. PS: Options not mentioned above were left as they were.

2. Then save the settings and close the connection dialog box.

3. Now go to the file `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/test-wifi` and change the mode to ap and save it. During the above steps I keep my wifi disabled, and after the last step I switch on my wifi again.

Now moving on to the main problem. As I switch on my wifi again, sometimes I get connected to the wifi automatically, but sometimes my wifi connection goes in a weird state where it is connected to my newly created test-wifi and disconnects the next moment and this keeps on happening again and again until I switch off wifi. Whenever my wifi connection reaches this weird state, I can't connect to my ap-hotspot until I reboot my laptop again. So in other words I can't create a hotspot until I reboot my laptop once. And even after rebooting the laptop, there is no guarantee that I will be able to create a hotspot as sometimes it does not even connect after a reboot.

How do I solve this problem? Also please tell me the commands to get my system details if necessary.

Comment: Reposted from a comment by JimJim2000: *P.S. To make the wifi access point the following howto was used https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-create-hotspots-in-Ubuntu-14-04*.

Comment: Just a curiosity, instead of rebooting or simply  after you modify it, did you tried a `sudo service networking restart`?

Comment: @Hastur, Yeah actually I try that every time hoping that it might work with the new kernel upgrade, but the same result every time i.e. it again starts to disconnect and reconnect again and again.

Comment: where you able to solve this issue? I am also facing similar issue.

Comment: Sorry but I don't exactly remember how I solved it. I most likely upgraded to a newer version of ubuntu available at that time.